# Sample code containing expression like {{ $title }} cause blank page in Laravel

Tags: html, web, laravel-5, blogger

I built a blog in Laravel to post some programming tutorials, but I faced a problem; when I have some expression (sample code) like below

```html
@foreach($items as $item)
    <div>{{ $item->name }}</div>
@endforeach
```

or if I have Angular sample code

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item.name }}</div>
```

the above sample codes cause a blank page,
in the console, there is no error, but in the development tool element tab body tag is empty. look at this link https://coffeequery.com/posts/loop-in-angular I looked everywhere to find a solution but couldn't.
I think the browser trying to evaluate this expression, what should I do to tell the browser to ignore it?
thanks.

Comment: Enable debug mode and see what's the error.

Comment: dear Robo, there is no error in the console, as I said; body tag is also empty.

Comment: What is for sure, you shouldn't put Angular curly braces like that in your Blade template. It should be `@{{ item.name }}` to avoid clash with Blade.

Comment: I tried @{{item.name}} but couldn't be solved, @ symbol couldn't skip the expression from the evaluation. before I create this issue in here, I had a conversation in this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/showing-a-variable-inside-cause-to-blank-page-in-laravel link too

Comment: What is the final source of your page? I'm pretty sure the error is somewhere else. But it's weird you claim you have `debug` on and you see no error.

Comment: I can't see any error, this is a link to the problem https://coffeequery.com/posts/test in this link inspect it and you will see what I see.

Comment: Looks like your `app.js` is messy. If you remove the script in your `app.js`, the page shows just fine. That's because you have frontend library hooked up to overwrite contents in `#app` element. I see Vue.js there as well.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following code:

```html
<code>&lt;div *ngFor="let item of items"&gt;@{{item.name}}&lt;/div&gt;</code>
```

Your Vue.js instance tries to evaluate the curly brackets and silently throws an error, which results in displaying empty `#app` element. I suggest using `v-text` attribute instead:

```html
<code v-text="'&lt;div *ngFor=&quot;let item of items&quot;&gt;{{item.name}}&lt;/div&gt;'"></code>
```

Comment: <code></code> added by prism, if Vue interapt I will remove it from Laravel I don't use it's components.
and I'll let you know if worked. thanks again